# R code for creating dataframes including unused categories?

Tags: r, dataframe, plyr

I am trying to make all my data frames in r have the same levels in a categorical column so that, when I make barplots of them all, they are comparable with some having "unused factors" of frequency 0.

Currently I have multiple, separate data frames including a global data frame, then several broken down by region. Each one has a category column, then a frequency column. I have one "global" data frame with all the categories, but each of the regional data frames only have counts of certain categories found there. For example...

Global DF

| category | frequency |
| --- | --- |
| red | 2 |
| orange | 4 |
| yellow | 7 |
| green | 1 |
| blue | 4 |
| purple | 4 |

Current West Region DF

| category | frequency |
| --- | --- |
| orange | 2 |
| blue | 1 |
| purple | 3 |

Desired West Region DF

| category | frequency |
| --- | --- |
| red | 0 |
| orange | 2 |
| yellow | 0 |
| green | 0 |
| blue | 1 |
| purple | 3 |

This is all based on the original dataset which looks like:

| Region | Category |
| --- | --- |
| West | orange |
| West | orange |
| West | blue |
| West | purple |
| West | purple |
| West | purple |
| North | red |
| North | yellow |
| ... | ... |

I'm currently using ddply to create the regional DFs, but I can't figure out how to maintain categories of frequency = 0 in each one (as exemplified in the Desired West Regional DF above).
Thanks for any insight!

Answer (score 0):

You could convert `Category` to a `factor` and make the counts using `dplyr`'s  `count` which has a `.drop` option allowing you to keep empty categories:

I.e.

```r
library(dplyr)

df |>
  mutate(Category = as.factor(Category)) |>
  count(Region, Category, .drop = FALSE) |>
  filter(Region == "West")
```

Output:

```r
# A tibble: 6 × 3
  Region Category     n
  <chr>  <fct>    <int>
1 West   blue         1
2 West   green        0
3 West   orange       2
4 West   purple       3
5 West   red          0
6 West   yellow       0
```

Data:

```r
library(readr)

df <- read_table("Region    Category
West    orange
West    orange
West    blue
West    purple
West    purple
West    purple
North   red
North   yellow
North   green")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `base R`

```
subset(as.data.frame(table(df)), Region == "West")
   Region Category Freq
2    West     blue    1
4    West    green    0
6    West   orange    2
8    West   purple    3
10   West      red    0
12   West   yellow    0
```